# Windows 2008 Remote Desktop Connection Multiple Sessions

Tags: connection, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

Does anybody know how to adjust the number of RDC sessions for a specific user in Windows 2008 Server?

Would really appreciate it!

Thanks a million!

Comment: Please clarify your question: do you want to be able to use more than 2 sessions at the same time or do you want to (programmatically)  logon a new session?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. Yes, I do want to have 2 sessions at the same time using one windows account. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 2003 had 2 sessions + 1 console session, Windows 2008 has just 2. If you need more sessions you have to set the server in Application mode and buy Terminal Server Client Access Licenses or TS CAL's which were recently rebranded to RDP (Remote Desktop Services) CAL's.
PS: there are of course patches for Terminal Server on both 2003 and 2008 on the net but I assume you are not searching for those.

Comment: In case someone is looking for the patch: http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2008/10/21/patch-windows-2008-terminal-server-to-allow-more-than-2-concurrent-sessions/

Answer (score 0):

With windows 2003 you were limited to two sessions allowed at any time by default with the licence. To get access to more sessions you'll need to pay extra (If MS followed the same model).

You can find this in the Control panels, remote management section.

Comment: Thanks for this. But this applies to Windows 2008 as well?